# Opencart send customized email on new order

Tags: php, excel, email, opencart

I need to generate an excel file and send it over email to store owner on new orders.

I have inserted this code in public_html/catalog/model/checkout/order.php

```
//emails have been changed on purpose

            $email_to = "my email";
    $mail2 = new Mail();

    $mail2->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail2->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail2->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
    $mail2->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
    $mail2->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
    $mail2->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
    $mail2->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');            
    $mail2->setTo($email_to);
    $mail2->setFrom("info@storename.com");
    $mail2->setSender("info@storename.com");
    $mail2->setSubject("test send mail");
    $mail2->setText("test message body text");

    $mail2->send();
```

I have inserted the code above right after this:

```
// Admin Alert Mail

    if ($this->config->get('config_order_mail')) {
                    $subject = sprintf($language->get('text_new_subject'), html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), $order_id);

                    // HTML Mail
                    $data['text_greeting'] = $language->get('text_new_received');

                    if ($comment) {
                        if ($order_info['comment']) {
                            $data['comment'] = nl2br($comment) . '<br/><br/>' . $order_info['comment'];
                        } else {
                            $data['comment'] = nl2br($comment);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ($order_info['comment']) {
                            $data['comment'] = $order_info['comment'];
                        } else {
                            $data['comment'] = '';
                        }
                    }

                    $data['text_download'] = '';

                    $data['text_footer'] = '';

                    $data['text_link'] = '';
                    $data['link'] = '';
                    $data['download'] = '';

                    // Text
                    $text  = $language->get('text_new_received') . "\n\n";
                    $text .= $language->get('text_new_order_id') . ' ' . $order_id . "\n";
                    $text .= $language->get('text_new_date_added') . ' ' . date($language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added'])) . "\n";
                    $text .= $language->get('text_new_order_status') . ' ' . $order_status . "\n\n";
                    $text .= $language->get('text_new_products') . "\n";



                    foreach ($order_product_query->rows as $product) {
                        $text .= $product['quantity'] . 'x ' . $product['name'] . ' (' . $product['model'] . ') ' . html_entity_decode($this->currency->format($product['total'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? ($product['tax'] * $product['quantity']) : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\n";

                        $order_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_option WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND order_product_id = '" . $product['order_product_id'] . "'");

                        foreach ($order_option_query->rows as $option) {
                            if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                                $value = $option['value'];
                            } else {
                                $value = utf8_substr($option['value'], 0, utf8_strrpos($option['value'], '.'));
                            }

                            $text .= chr(9) . '-' . $option['name'] . ' ' . (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value) . "\n";
                        }
                    }

                    foreach ($order_voucher_query->rows as $voucher) {
                        $text .= '1x ' . $voucher['description'] . ' ' . $this->currency->format($voucher['amount'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']);
                    }

                    $text .= "\n";

                    $text .= $language->get('text_new_order_total') . "\n";

                    foreach ($order_total_query->rows as $total) {
                        $text .= $total['title'] . ': ' . html_entity_decode($this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\n";
                    }

                    $text .= "\n";

                    if ($order_info['comment']) {
                        $text .= $language->get('text_new_comment') . "\n\n";
                        $text .= $order_info['comment'] . "\n\n";
                    }

                    $mail = new Mail();
                    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
                    $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
                    $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
                    $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

                    $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
                    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
                    $mail->setText($text);
                    $mail->send();
```

I also have a script that generates excel file, but I have no idea how to combine both of them together.

Problems now:

1. Customized email is not sending on new order, but general email on new order is reaching with no problem.
2. Please give any ideas how to generate into excel the code on a Opencart CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was much easier than I was expected. 
Since nobody paid attention, I spent a couple of hours researching and found solution. So if somebody needs to generate an excel file that have to be sent to delivery company, here it is:

Open whether public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/model/checkout/order.php

or public_html/catalog/model/checkout/order.php cause for some people 2nd link worked but for me 1st link worked.

Search for this:

```
// Admin Alert Mail
```

then scroll down till this:

```
$mail = new Mail();
                $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
                $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
                $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
                $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

                $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
                $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
                $mail->setText($text);
                $mail->send();
```

Paste this code to generate the excel file:

```
//excel

                         $data2 = array(
        array("ORDER ID" => $order_id, "COMPANY NAME" => "Your company name", "ADDRESS LINE1" =>$data['shipping_address'], "ADDRESS LINE2" => $data['shipping_address_2'],"CONTACT PERSON"=>$order_info['shipping_firstname']." ".$order_info['shipping_lastname'],"CITY" =>$order_info['shipping_city'], "PHONE_1"=>$data['telephone'],"CONTENT" =>"", "WH NUMBER" =>$product['model'],"PIECES"=>$product['quantity'],"COD"=>"","Total"=>$order_info['total']),
          );

    function filterData(&$str)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
        if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }

    // file name for download
    $fileName = $order_id.".xls";



    $flag = false;
    foreach($data2 as $row) {
        if(!$flag) {
            // display column names as first row
         echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
            $flag = true;
        }
        // filter data
  array_walk($row, 'filterData');
           $rows=  implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n"  . implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";


        file_put_contents( $fileName, $rows);
    }

$mail->setTo('email of delivery company or any you need');
                $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/excel', $data));
                $mail->setText($text);
                $mail->send();
```

Go to public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/ and create a file excel.tpl.

Paste this to excel.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
<div style="width: 680px;"><a href="<?php echo $store_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $store_name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $store_name; ?>" style="margin-bottom: 20px; border: none;" /></a>



Find and order in excel file here:

<a href="http://yourwebsiteurl.com/<?php echo $order_id; ?>.xls">Download</a>

  <?php if ($customer_id) { ?>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_link; ?></p>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $link; ?></a></p>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($download) { ?>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_download; ?></p>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $download; ?></a></p>
  <?php } ?>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;" colspan="2"><?php echo $text_order_detail; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><b><?php echo $text_order_id; ?></b> <?php echo $order_id; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_date_added; ?></b> <?php echo $date_added; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_payment_method; ?></b> <?php echo $payment_method; ?><br />
          <?php if ($shipping_method) { ?>
          <b><?php echo $text_shipping_method; ?></b> <?php echo $shipping_method; ?>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><b><?php echo $text_email; ?></b> <?php echo $email; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_telephone; ?></b> <?php echo $telephone; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_ip; ?></b> <?php echo $ip; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_order_status; ?></b> <?php echo $order_status; ?><br /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php if ($comment) { ?>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_instruction; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $comment; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php } ?>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_payment_address; ?></td>
        <?php if ($shipping_address) { ?>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_shipping_address; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $payment_address; ?></td>
        <?php if ($shipping_address) { ?>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $shipping_address; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_product; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_model; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_quantity; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_price; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_total; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['name']; ?>
          <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
          <br />
          &nbsp;<small> - <?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['description']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">1</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;" colspan="4"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_footer; ?></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now try to order something from a web site and it should work.